# How do I squash commits in one branch while keeping them in the other?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-workflow

I commit often. I want to keep my history of fine-grained commits in a branch on my local Git repository, and just push much coarser-grained commits into the remote repo.

I want to be able to find corresponding commits in my "fine-grained" local branch.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep your local branch out of the remote:

1. Create and checkout the local branch (let's call it `Ruby` branch).  Commit as needed all your fine-grained commits.

   > ```
   > m1 - m2     <- master, origin/master
   >   \
   >    r1 - r2 - r3  <- Ruby (fine grained commits - no origin/Ruby)
   > ```
2. Whenever you have a coarse-grained piece of work complete in `Ruby` that you want to send to the remote, merge it an appropriate branch on your local repo that is also a branch on the remote.  Let's assume this branch is `master`, but it might be something else like `dev`, `release-xyz`, `feature-123`, etc.)

   > ```
   > m1 - m2 ------- m3   <- master (new merge m3 from Ruby)
   >   \            /
   >    r1 - r2 - r3  <- Ruby
   > ```
3. To create merge commit (m3 in diagram above), checkout the branch to be merged (i.e. `master`, etc.) and don't rebase the `Ruby` branch onto `master`, which would copy all of the commits `r1`, `r2`, and `r3` onto `master`.  Instead, just do a normal merge with a commit (i.e. `git merge Ruby`).  In the merge commit, summarize the group of changes in the commit message as you see fit.
4. Make sure that `master` is checked out, and push to the remote - or use specific push commands to make sure you are pushing `master`, and not `Ruby`.

   > ```
   > m1 - m2 ------- m3   <- master (origin/master updated to m3 from push)
   >   \            /
   >    r1 - r2 - r3  <- Ruby (still no origin/Ruby - local only)
   > ```

The idea is that we keep `Ruby` as a local branch only, and never push it to the remote.  Of course, there is no harm in pushing `Ruby` if anyone else should have access to those fine-grained commits.  Also, by pushing `Ruby`, it will be saved as a backup, in case your PC goes down, and you can clone it to another PC if needed and yours isn't available.  So you might want to think about just making `Ruby` a branch you push to the remote - but even so, you probably will still want to merge with a single commit as described above.

Comment: Added some diagrams to help with the visualization.  As always, I highly recommend a visual git tool like Git Extensions (open-source, cross platform) to visualize the branches, see the index and commit diffs easily, etc.

Comment: I tried that, it did not wok. `git merge Ruby` copies all the intermediate commits into `main` branch.

Comment: I can retest this on a clean repo, but that isn't normal merge behavior, you should have to specifically cherry-pick or rebase to copy any commits.  A merge doesn't look at individual commits, it just looks at the total sum differences since the last common parent, and commits all of them in a single commit.  Do you maybe have some special macros set up or some config settings on this repo, or globally, that would cause different behavior?  Are you using `git merge Ruby` directly at the command line?  You may need to post the output of that command from the console for more help.

Comment: You may want to try this on a clean repo with some simple test commits until the behavior is understood.

Comment: `git merge --squash Ruby` achieved the desired effect for me.